# How to insert a PostGIS GEOMETRY Point in Sequelize ORM?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgis, sequelize.js

I am trying to insert a row in a table that has a geometry column in Sequelize.js ORM.
I have latitude, longitude and altitude and need to convert it to a point first so I can Insert it as a geometry.

The PostGIS stored procedure that does the converting is

```
ST_MakePoint( longitude, latitude, altitude )
```

To Insert a row I am using the sequelize model.create function

```
models.Data.create({    
  location: "ST_MakePoint("+request.params.lon+", "+request.params.lat+", "+request.params.alt+")", // PSUEDO code, How can I call this function?
  speed: request.params.spd,
  azimuth: request.params.azi,
  accuracy: request.params.acc
});
```

Now what I want to do Is make the field `location` have the returned result of `"ST_MakePoint("+request.params.lon+", "+request.params.lat+", "+request.params.alt+")"` when I insert the row.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Expanding on l0oky's answer, the [integration test](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/75b2503ac6609a7a07bd0fbc6edc19e1681c802b/test/integration/model/geometry.test.js) has a lot of good clues on how to use the json with varying types of Geometry.  Basically, it appears that sequelize will stringify the provided geometry object assuming that it is valid GeoJSON and pipe that into the PostGIS function ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.  Therefore, one can just follow the [GeoJSON spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) for geometry objects.

**Points:**

```
var point = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [39.807222,-76.984722]};

User.create({username: 'username', geometry: point }).then(function(newUser) {
...
});
```

**Linestrings:**

```
var line = { type: 'LineString', 'coordinates': [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0] ] };

User.create({username: 'username', geometry: line }).then(function(newUser) {
...
});
```

**Polygons:**

```
var polygon = { type: 'Polygon', coordinates: [
             [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0],
               [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
             ]};

User.create({username: 'username', geometry: polygon }).then(function(newUser) {
...
});
```

**Setting a custom SRID:**

```
var point = { 
  type: 'Point', 
  coordinates: [39.807222,-76.984722],
  crs: { type: 'name', properties: { name: 'EPSG:4326'} }
};

User.create({username: 'username', geometry: point }).then(function(newUser) {
...
});
```

Answer (score 6):

After a bit of researching I found that Sequelize 3.5.1 ( is supporting GEOMETRY ) had a [test](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/3828/files#r33254556) that inserts a `Point`.

```
var point = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [39.807222,-76.984722] }; 
return User.create({ username: 'user', email: ['foo@bar.com'], location: point})
```

Where `location` is a GEOMETRY field. This way I don't need to call `ST_MakePoint` manually, sequelize takes care of that.