# Insert/Update PostGis Geometry with Sequelize ORM

Tags: sequelize.js, postgis, geojson

I have extracted models of some PostGis layers with sequelize-auto, giving:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
return sequelize.define('table', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  geom: {
    type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('POINT', 4326),
    allowNull: true,
  },
...
```

On GET sequelize sends the geom to the client as GeoJSON:

```
{
  "type":"Point",
  "coordinates":[11.92164103734465,57.67219297300486]
}
```

When I try to save this back PosGis errors with:

```
ERROR:  Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)
```

This answer gives a god indication of how to add the SRID ([How to insert a PostGIS GEOMETRY Point in Sequelize ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059758/how-to-insert-a-postgis-geometry-point-in-sequelize-orm)),

```
var point = { 
  type: 'Point', 
  coordinates: [39.807222,-76.984722],
  crs: { type: 'name', properties: { name: 'EPSG:4326'} }
};

User.create({username: 'username', geometry: point }).then(function(newUser) {
...
});
```

I understand that SRID used to be a feature that was removed from sequelize (https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4054).

Does anyone know a way to hook into Sequelize so that the srid is added to the GeoJson sent to PostGis? Where to put it? In a setter on the model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that Sequelize does not save the SRID when saving a `GEOMETRY` field (note, that it correctly saves the SRID on a `GEOGRAPHY` field). Then when you update that model in the future, the update will fail because it does not have a SRID set on the `GEOMETRY` field as expected in the model definition.

This isn't a desirable solution, but you can use Sequelize's `beforeSave` hook to always speciify the coordinates system to use.

```
myDatabase.define('user', {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  geometry: {
    type: Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POINT', 4326)
  }
}, {
  hooks: {
    beforeSave: function(instance) {
      if (instance.geometry && !instance.geometry.crs) {
        instance.geometry.crs = {
          type: 'name',
          properties: {
            name: 'EPSG:4326'
          }
        };
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @mcranston18, that's what I was looking for. As you say, not ideal, but I shall use it :)

Comment: I've tried this, without joy. beforeSave (sequelize v4.20) isn't getting called - I've put a console.log in that never shows. I can't post the code here, but it looks more or less as yours. Any ideas?

Comment: Now posted new question, with code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358408/sequelize-beforesave-hook-not-firing

Answer (score 4):

Declare the column type as: `DataTypes.GEOMETRY('Point')`,

Set the model attribute as:

```
{
  type: 'Point',
  coordinates: [ lat, long ],
  crs: { type: 'name', properties: { name: 'EPSG:4326'} }
}
```