# coordinates does not exist in type 'GeometryDataType'

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js, postgis

This is a follow up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059758/how-to-insert-a-postgis-geometry-point-in-sequelize-orm) question. Now I am using the point object correctly however I get this error:

```
src/actions/collectGpsData.ts:22:43 - error TS2322: Type '{ type: string; coordinates: any[]; }' is not assignable to type 'GeometryDataType'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"coordinates"' does not exist in type 'GeometryDataType'.

22       place.location = { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [point.latitude, point.longitude] };
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

[image]

```
import { Action } from "actionhero"; // No GeometryDataType sequelize.js definition
import { Place } from "../models/Place";

export class CollectGpsData extends Action {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = "collectGpsData";
    this.description = "Collects GPS data and inserts it into the database";
    this.outputExample = {};
    this.inputs = {
      gpsdata: {
        required:true
      }
    }
  }

  async run(data) {
    var GPSdata = data.params.gpsdata;
    GPSdata.forEach(point => {
      var place = new Place();
      place.deviceimei = point.deviceimei;
      place.location = { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [point.latitude, point.longitude] }; //error line
    });
  }
}
```

Why am I getting this error? and how can I avoid this error in the future?

Comment: Are you defining `GeometryDataType`, or is it defined by a third party library? How is it being defined?

Comment: My import definition doesn't include `GeometryDataType`

Comment: Can you show the definition for `Place`?

Comment: Here it is https://gist.github.com/krlicmuhamed/199c0bc3560a08718b553f3f609acbcd

Comment: So it is in a model, GeometryDataType, does it accept coordinates array?

Comment: Here's the definition for geometry and geograpy https://gist.github.com/krlicmuhamed/199c0bc3560a08718b553f3f609acbcd#file-definition-ts-L39

Comment: Actually definition of GeometryDataType doesn't allow for coordinates at all https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/data-types.js~GEOMETRY.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered it in [your GitHub issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12951#issuecomment-774836246):

> Hello @krlicmuhamed!
>
> As @nainkunal933 noted, please include a complete code sample next time. The code you posted does not show how `User` is defined, for example. Please use a [sequelize-sscce](https://github.com/papb/sequelize-sscce).
>
> That said, I took the time to look into what's happening and tried to figure it out.
>
> So, first of all, this issue is typescript-only. The code works fine in runtime. Please include this information directly next time.
>
> I ventured into your stackoverflow question and comments and found this:
>
> https://gist.github.com/krlicmuhamed/199c0bc3560a08718b553f3f609acbcd#file-places-ts-L22
>
> Did you find any documentation instructing you to use this specific type explicitly here? If yes, please post the link so I can fix it. Regardless, I don't blame you because we really should have a set of recommended types to apply on each data type. It turns out `GeometryDataType` is not the correct type to use in this case.
>
> The solution is to install `@types/geojson`:
>
> - `npm install --save-dev @types/geojson`
>
> Then, import `Geometry`:
>
> ```
> import type { Geometry } from '@types/geojson'
> ```
>
> And then replace that line of code in which you put `GeometryDataType` with `Geometry`:
>
> ```
>    @AllowNull(false)
>    @Column(DataTypes.GEOMETRY)
> -  location: GeometryDataType;
> +  location: Geometry;
> ```